# Add count of child table to select from parent with hibernate criteria API

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How can I execute this SQL query using the Hibernate Criteria API?

```
SELECT c.*, count(r.id) FROM COURSE c left join REFERRAL r on c.id = r.course_id group by c.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems close enough:

```
Criteria criteria = currentSession().createCriteria(Referral.class, "r");
criteria.createAlias("r.course", "course");

ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList();
projections.add(Projections.groupProperty("course.id"));
projections.add(Projections.count("r.id"));

return list(criteria
        .setProjection(projections));
```